# could not access directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data": Permission denied ,while trying to setup database cluster

Tags: linux, postgresql, centos, redhat

I am trying to set up Postgres in Redhat. I do the following steps:

```
$ sudo yum install postgresql-server postgresql-contrib
```

It is successfully installed. Then i try to set up a database cluster.

```
$ initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

I get the error:

```
initdb: could not access directory "/usr/local/pgsql/data": Permission denied
```

New to linux. Not being able to move forward

Figured out the solution. I went to the specified folder and changed its access permission. It worked after that.

Answer (score 5):

The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/install-short.html) notes that the `/usr/local/pgsql/data` directory needs to be owned by the `postgres` user.

To do this, you can run the following command:

```
chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

And if that doesn't work, you might need to also use `sudo`:

```
sudo chown postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running the first command as a superuser and the second as a regular user. Try

```
 sudo initdb -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

Comment: Did that, it says 'cannot be run as root`

Comment: Check out the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/app-initdb.html), it looks like it explains a work around.

Answer (score 0):

While installing postgre, I used

```
su - postgres
```

to connect to the specific user with root privileges. Then, the following returned a success

```
/usr/pgsql-9.5/bin/initdb
```